# Django Json post request Payload error

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, django-request

Hi I am accessing an url with payload.
I tried this code for payload:

```
app_id = "Dert/dedff/12i="
payload = "{\n \"app_id\": \"{}\"\n}".format(app_id)
```

When do request, Django give following error.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.10.4
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
"\n 'app_id'"
```

Comment: it should be like `'{"app_id": "{}"}'.format(app_id)`.

Comment: Tried that but issue is app_id variable has / in it so gives error. However solved it by using double braces.

Comment: Do you expect to have a string with the `app_id` included, or just build a new `dict` with `app_id` as the key and `"Dert/dedff/12i="` as value  ?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Posted answer it worked somehow

Comment: awesome... I thought you wanted it as a `dict`

Comment: You shouldn't really be constructing JSON manually like this at all... there is a `json` module in Python that does this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below code

```
app_id = "Dert/dedff/12i="
payload = "{{\n \"app_id\": \"{}\"\n}}".format(app_id)
```

It worked.
Instead of single braces, double braces are required.